# C# "Version-Updater"

Tags: c#

I want to increase the last number of the version (for Example: 1.0.0.0 -> 1.0.0.1).
I would prefer to kep this code :)

The actuall code looks like that:

```
private void UpdateApplicationVersion(string filepath)
    {
        string currentApplicationVersion = "1.2.3.4"
        string newApplicationVersionDigit = ((currentApplicationVersion.Split('.')[3]) + 1).ToString();


        string newApplicatonVersion = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i <= currentApplicationVersion.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 7)
            {
                newApplicatonVersion += newApplicationVersionDigit ;
            }
            else
            {
                newApplicatonVersion += currentApplicationVersion.ToCharArray()[i];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be done by parsing all components of the version, manipulate the last one and put them together again as follows.

```
string[] Components = currentApplicationVersion.Split('.');
int Maj = Convert.ToInt32(Components[0]);
int Min = Convert.ToInt32(Components[1]);
int Revision = Convert.ToInt32(Components[2]);
int Build = Convert.ToInt32(Components[3]);
Build++;
string newApplicationVersion 
  = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", Maj, Min, Revision, Build);
```

Answer (score 6):

Do it simple way,

```
    string v1 = "1.0.0.1";
    string v2 = "1.0.0.4";

    var version1 = new Version(v1);
    var version2 = new Version(v2);
    var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
    if (result > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("version1 is greater");
    else if (result < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("version2 is greater");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("versions are equal");
```

Comment: Sir nice answer but it didn't work (that could be a mistake on my side). :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Split` and `Join`:

```
string currentApplicationVersion = "1.2.3.4";

int[] data = currentApplicationVersion.Split('.')
  .Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
  .ToArray();

// The last version component is data[data.Length - 1]
// so you can, say, increment it, e.g.
data[data.Length - 1] += 1;

// "1.2.3.5"
String result = String.Join(".", data);
```

Comment: Sir nice answer but it didn't work (that could be a mistake on my side). :)

Comment: @Ken Zöggeler: I'm sorry for typo: it should be `x =>` instead of `x = >` (extra space)

Comment: the problem was "Cultureinfo" it didn't exist :/

Comment: add `using System.Globalization;` to obtain `Cultureinfo`

Comment: oh i didn't konw that ...
as i said im not good at programming :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a class build for working with version numbers. It's called `Version` and can be found in the `System` namespace

you can parse your current version by passing the string representing the version to the constructor

```
var currentApplicationVersion = new Version(currentApplicationVersionString);
```

and then get the new one with another of the constructors

```
var newApplicationVersion = new Version(
                                 currentApplicationVersion.Major,
                                 currentApplicationVersion.Minor,
                                 currentApplicationVersion.Build,
                                 currentApplicationVersion.Revision +1     
                            );
```

and then simply call `.ToString()` if you need it as a string

Comment: Yeah I know you already have a solution to the problem but wanted to show a solution using the build in features of the base class library. It's generally recommended to use the BCL rather than implementing your own version of the same functionality (in this case the parsing of the version number and construncting the string representation of the same)

Comment: Thx anyway :)
just a little question : "Bcl?" :o